# EventLimit doesnt seem to work

Tags: fullcalendar

Here is the JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/362/

For some reason I cannot seem to get the eventLimit property to work correctly, or at all in fact.  Now it states in the documentation that:

`A value of true will limit the number of events to the height of the day cell.`

However I cannot see how to set the height of the day cells either.  There are height properties for the header, and the calender body but the does not seem to affect the individual day cells.

What's annoying me is that on the front page of the fullcalendar website (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) It seems to work fine, without setting any height variables at all simply just `eventLimit: 'true'`.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using FullCalendar 2.0.0 and the demo page is using FullCalendar 2.1.0.

If you check this [blog post](http://blog.arshaw.com/1/post/2014/08/fullcalendar-210-released.html) describing the changes for the version 2.1.0 (which was released today), you will see that what you need was released on this version.

So, you only need to update the Javascript and CSS and that will work.